# How to get access to the already opened CATDocument of an existing CATIA session?

Tags: c++, catia, caa

I'm facing an issue when trying to access to currently opened CATDocument of an already opened CATIA session.

What I have:

- A pointer to a CATIAApplication object:

```
CLSID clsid;
HRESULT hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"CATIA.Application", &clsid);
CComPtr<IUnknown> pCatiaSession;
hr = GetActiveObject(clsid, NULL, &pCatiaSession);
CATIAApplication * pApp = NULL;
hr = pSession->QueryInterface(IID_CATIAApplication, (void**) &pApp);
CATIADocument * pDocument = NULL;
hr = pApp->get_ActiveDocument(pDocument);
```

What I need:
a pointer to a CATDocument, to be able to work on the product structure.

I tried to retrieve the path of the CATIADocument, and then reopen it with `CATDocumentServices::Open`, but the product was loaded a second time in some kind of ghost session because nothing is visible, as in a batch mode. I also tried to use CATDocumentServices, CATSessionServices and CATSession methods, but nothing does the trick...

Comment: #include "CATDocument.h"

CATDocument *pDocument = NULL;
pApp->get_ActiveDocument(&pDocument);


https://www.maruf.ca/files/caadoc/CAAMmrTechArticles/CAAMmrStructurePartDoc.htm

Same result?

Comment: get_ActiveDocument will retrieve a CATIADocument, not a CATDocument. CATDocument is not an interface, so it cannot be casted (does not inherits from it either of course).